# remote debug visual studio linux

Tags: visual-studio, ssh, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I'm currently stuck at one point trying to remote debug with my raspberry pi.

I have Visual studio 2017 installed. I created a linux console Project and connected VS17 to the raspberry via ssh successfully. Now I wanted to Code a simple Input Output program in c++ just to test the functionality. While I could see the result of cout perfectly in the console in VS17 I couldn't write an Input. At the point of cin the console didnt react on my Input. Maybe someone has had a similar Problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There have been various problems with i/o in console applications but if you ensure you are on the latest VS2017 (version 15.5.6) **and** debug in `GDB` mode (i.e. change from the default `gdbserver` in project properties) everything should work fine.

You should also flush the terminal buffer by putting a newline after your prompt message otherwise the application will be waiting for input *before* the prompt appears in the console window.

Some of the issues you might encounter are discussed on [the VCLinux github site](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/119) .

Comment: You mean stop using the gdb client locally and run it on the raspberry? I wil try that thanks.

Comment: That's an odd way to look at it because `gdb` or `gdbserver` and the VCLinux gdb client are not under your control. But I suppose you could represent it like that.

VS has two debugging modes that you can set, choose `GDB` mode so that GDB runs entirely on the Linux remote and VS communicates via the command line interface over `ssh` . This was the reason why until recently console applications could not accept input when debugging in GDB mode. But it's all fine in the current release.